# Is there a community for questions about Windows?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I’ve been looking for communities  for questions about Windows but all I could find was [Windows Phone](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/). Is there one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps you can ask your question on [Super User](https://superuser.com/), as help section states that Super User is for

- Computer Hardware
- Computer Software
- Personal and home computer networking

Also, [41,317 questions related to Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows) can be found on Super User.